# Уникальное id для файла php

Tags: php, файлы, строки, while

Есть скрипт, который считает количество файлов в папке , и на основании подсчетов присваивает к имени файла уникальный id (int).

То есть если файлов 39 то в переменную записывается 40, после там же создается файл и общее количество файлов уже становится равно 40.

```
$number  = $i; // сюда записывается результат подсчета файлов в папке 

$text='example';

$format='.php';

$fulltext.= $text . $number . $format; //получилось example40.php
```

После полной операции в `main` файл добавляется текст, в список вида :

```
...

example37.php

example38.php

example39.php

example40.php
```

И в случае удаления из середины списка например `: example38.php` и удаления его файла

После повторной процедуры подсчета файлов скрипт посчитает снова 39 файлов в папке потом добавит к подсчету +1 и запишет в main файл , и мы получим строку вида

...

```
example37.php

example39.php

example40.php

example40.php
```

Есть идеи как решить проблему ? Вот скрипт подсчета

//Подсчет количества файлов в папке content

```
    $path = 'content'; 
    $dir = opendir ("$path"); 
    $i = 0; 
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {


          if (strpos($file, '.txt',1) ) {
          $i++;
      }
    }
    $i++;
$number = $i;
```

Comment: используйте абсолютно случайное название файла, либо ищите максимальное вхождение в названиях существующих

Comment: абсолютно случайное название догадался , пытаюсь реализовать через rand(0, 900) , по подробнее про максимальное вхождение существующих можно?

Comment: md5 хэш содержимого, но зачем?

Answer (score 2):

`string tempnam ( string $dir , string $prefix )`

> Создаёт файл с уникальным именем в определённой директории...

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.tempnam.php

Answer (score 0):

Можно генерить уникальное имя файла, например, так:

```
$dir = __DIR__; //путь до нужной папки
do {
$filename = md5(microtime(1).'-'.rand(0,500))
}
while (file_exists($dir.'/'.$filename);
```

Если вам нужно решать вопросы по поводу уникальных имен по маске, типа **example23.php** , то можно так:

```
$dir = __DIR__; //путь до нужной папки
$files = glob($dir.'/example*.php');
$fileLast = end($files);
preg_match('/example([\d]+).php/s', $fileLast, $match);
$fileNew = $dir.'/example'.($match[1]+1).'.php';
```

Не претендую на самые оптимизированные или идеальные решения. Но вполне рабочий вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт отделяет последнее число из названия файла и прибавляет 1 к максимальному имеющемуся.

Работает с любыми расширениями и именами файлов, даже не содержащих цифры.

```php
$path = 'content'; 
$dir = opendir ($path); 

$keys = array();

while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
      if (preg_match("/[^\d](?P<number>\d+)\.\w+$/", $file, $matches)) {
          $key = $matches['number'];
      } else {
          $key = 0;
      }
      $keys[] = $key;
}

sort($keys);
$maxKey = end($keys);

echo $maxKey+1; // Выведет необходимое число для следующего имени файла
```